# Google Analytics -

Tags: google-analytics

I created a new custom dimension on November 9th called `Purchase Prediction Score`. I previously had another custom dimension called `Cookie Id`.

So the goal of the `Purchase Prediction Score` is to score every returning user and each user will get a score `hot`, `warm` or `cold`. The `Cookie Id` is a string with this format: `937464.746545`

I created a custom report and I found out that I have `Purchase Prediction Score` data even before to have created that custom dimension on the 9th. The first time I pushed Purchase Prediction Score data was on the `9th`. What can be the explanation?
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask that title isnt very question like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the shield in top of the report (over "All users" segment, not visible in your screenshot) a message will appear saying that:

> The table rows have been filtered to include only the data for
> "*Purchase Prediction Score*", **while the chart and table headers
> include totals for all data**.

So this is the reason.